# Proof of the the inequality

Tags: inequality

I have the following conditions:
$$a_1<0; \quad a_2, \; a_3, \; a_4 >0$$
$$\sigma_{2, 1} = a_2a_3+a_3a_4+a_4a_2 > 0$$
$$\sigma_{2, 2} = a_1a_3+a_3a_4+a_4a_1 > 0$$
$$\sigma_{2, 3} = a_1a_2+a_2a_4+a_4a_1 > 0$$
$$\sigma_{2, 4} = a_1a_2+a_2a_3+a_3a_1 > 0$$

Is it true, that
$$\sigma_4=a_1a_2a_3 + a_1a_2a_4 + a_1a_3a_4 + a_2a_3a_4 > 0?$$

Comment: Are you sure $\sigma_{2, 1} = a_2a_3 + a_3a_4 + a_4a_1$ and not $a_2a_3 + a_3a_4 + a_2a_4$?

Comment: @ntntnt Your expression is obviously positive.

Comment: Right, it just seemed as if $\sigma_{2, i}$ was just the sum of all pairs without $a_i.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are an infinite number of counter-examples.

For instance, let $a_2 = a_3 = a_4 =1$. Then any $a_1$ such that -$1/2 < a_1 < -1/3$ is a counter-example.

Comment: Out of curiosity how did you figure this out?

Comment: @ntntnt It's immediately obvious.

Comment: Upon second look you are correct.